# Lenovo T440s fingerprint reader stopped working

Tags: lenovo-laptop

Had my laptop for a couple years now - but a couple days ago, fingerprint reader would not light up green when OS is ready to log you in.
Looked in device manager too but couldn't find an entry for FPR. Was hoping to update drivers or something.

Can someone please add `t440s` as a tag and delete this comment? I don't have enough points.

Comment: we're trying to get rid of company tags. Model tags are much too specific. So, no, we shouldn't have a T440s tag

Comment: Thanks @JourneymanGeek - but BIOS settings are so different in for each companies laptop - even between their own models. Heck, even the way to get to BIOS is different.

Comment: Well, the full text of your questions are searchable, If people search for the model and fingerprint reader they will find it

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS
Hit `Enter` on the first screen you see when turning on machine. It says Hit Enter on there too. Then press `F1` to enter BIOS.

In BIOS under fingerprint reader, there is a setting which was called Fingerprint Type or something. I had the value `External -> Internal` selected. I changed it to be `Internal only`. Hit `F10` to save and exit. Machine will reboot and fingerprint is working again now.